# Outlook VBA - How to get email item from user input

Tags: vba, outlook, user-input, mailitem

Although Im quite experienced with Excel VBA, Im not so much in regards of Outlook VBA (started yesterday, literally), so Im uncertain on how to get this simple task accomplished:

I created some coding to get a specific e-mail from the Inbox and then parse it and forward - that part is all good and well. Currently the code autodetects and retrieve the e-mail item using a set of parameters to filter through the Inbox. However, now I need to expand this code so that it can work with *any* e-mail item, and not only with that specific e-mail.

**My idea is to get the user to input which e-mail item he/she wants to parse and forward**, instead of getting the code to look in a specific place. How can that be done? The user input methods that I use regularly are InputBox (which returns a string) and GetOpenFileName, none of them suitable to pointing to a mail item within Outlook.

I thought about making the code work with the currently open e-mail item, but often the users have several e-mail items opened at once - forcing them to leave only one open for the code to work is not viable. Also, the code will be ran by people who have little to no IT expertise, so requesting things such as paths is also not an option. Is there any method for this?

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/ Appears you want to reference an active or selected item.

Comment: Try this solution
[Insert Item Dialog for user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76898310/how-to-open-insert-item-dialog-from-outlook-using-vba)

Answer (score 0):

I figured that working with Active MailItem is the way to go, as @niton suggested as well. I used a coding very similar to the one in [this post](http://www.outlookcode.com/codedetail.aspx?id=50), although I had to develop the handlers in case the user has other types of Objects active at the moment (AppointmentItems, for instance) or have multiple items selected. Final solution wasn't that much elegant - I was wishing for some sort of system input box where the user could point to the mail or something, but this works.